# Which SharePoint web service would I use to upload an image from <input type="file"... />?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, web-services

The copy service seems to want to take an item from one source url to another.  I looked in the list service but nothing jumped out at me as an option.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the Lists web service, the UpdateListItems method wouldn't you? "The Lists Web service provides methods for working with SharePoint lists, content types, list items, and files." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists%28v=office.12%29

Comment: I don't think you can specify file contents (the image itself) with UpdateListItems can you?

Comment: This shows a possibility, http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--development-programming/updatelistitems-document-library-59225.shtml. It pushes the file to the library then updates metadata. This shows how with the Copy web service, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/f135aaa2-3345-483f-ade4-e4fd597d50d4

Comment: This is all over my head, but I've got some familiarity with working with the web services client side and those are the only 2 sources I know that can push data to lists/libraries.